# Playing laser sound while pressing spacebar as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

Trying to figure out a code for my ship when i press spacebar and fires the laser a sound will play

```
private var reqButton:URLRequest = new URLRequest("laser.mp3");
private var buttonSound:Sound = new Sound(reqButton);

if (key.isDown(Keyboard.SPACE))
            {
                fireBullet();
                buttonSound.play();
            }
```

ok this worked the only 2 things i need was to add

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.Sound;
```

Comment: Do you have a sound file in your library ?

Comment: yes i added to my library but i can't find how to type the as3 code. when i press spacebar the laser sound will play

Comment: Should it play once each time you press the button ? or is it continuous as long as the button is held down ?

Comment: imagine that you have a spaceship and when u press spacebar it fires a laser ( plays sound)

Comment: I got that part - read my question again, because it's very specific whereas what you just repeated is vague. You didn't answer either of my questions with your comment.

Comment: sorry,
continuous as long the button is held down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this if you have an external sound in an "audio" folder

```
var reqButton:URLRequest = new URLRequest("audio/button.mp3"); 
var buttonSound:Sound = new Sound(reqButton);
```

and then your keypress code:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
    function keyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {

        switch(event.charCode)
        {   
        case 32:  //Space Bar 
            //trace("Space Bar");
             buttonSound.play();
            break;


        }
    }
```

Comment: The asker is actually seeking the code for key event listener and handling event to play the sound when spacebar is pressed.

Comment: i tried the code and i get multiple errors i forget to mention that i m using classes as3. 

i follow the tutorial from the spaceship game (asgamer)

Comment: I edited the code to add the key press event and the stage listener

Comment: `switch(event.charCode)
    {   
    case 32:  //Space Bar 
        //trace("Space Bar");
         buttonSound.play();
        break;


    }` adding this inside this 
`if (key.isDown(Keyboard.SPACE))
   {
    fireBullet();
                
   }`

Comment: you also may need to add the import statement for the URLRequest - import flash.net.URLRequest;

Comment: This will just have the sound play once, when you push down the button. If he wants continuous/repeating of the sound until the key is released, this will not work as he expects. Just pointing this out because he mentioned that in the comments of the question.